# How do I solve the system of matrix equations?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Knowing that $A=\begin{pmatrix}
-1 &2 \\ 
 1&1 
\end{pmatrix},B=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2\\ 
 0&1 
\end{pmatrix},C=\begin{pmatrix}
2 &2 \\ 
3 &1 
\end{pmatrix}$ solve the system

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
AX+CY=BAC\\ 
CX-BY=CAB
\end{matrix}\right.$$
 So guys how do I solve this. I know how to find the inverse of matrix and I guess I should use it can you show me how to start and what to do after?

Comment: Hello - any ideas? What have you tried?

Comment: Happy to help, but notice that accepting correct answers is highly appreciated, and probably the courtesy that is expected. Just think about the fact that "guys how do I solve this" is something that resonates with friends and family, but we don't have the pleasure to have built a personal relationship.

Comment: I tried this but I think it take too long and maybe there is other way $\left\{\begin{matrix}
AX+CY=BAC/*C^{-1}\\ 
CX-BY=CAB/*B^{-1}
\end{matrix}\right.=>\left\{\begin{matrix}
C^{-1}AX+Y=C^{-1}BAC\\ 
B^{-1}CX-Y=B^{-1}CAB
\end{matrix}\right.$ and I did first equation+second equation to get rid of Y. It take a little too long tho.

Comment: @AntoniParellada what do you mean?

Comment: Well, I went as far as to use my own cell phone while in transit to make sure I hadn't misled you on [my answer this morning](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2084042/152225), and I even posted a line of code for you to effortlessly verify the result as correct. Five points up, and the answer remains un-accepted. Totally uncool IMHO.

Comment: Oh dude the answer is correct there but it is not the only one. Anyway thank you for your effort. Who told you I did not appreciate it?

Comment: @OvyOvy Again, there is some etiquette to be followed: First of all, I am not "dude", and you should be more respectful. Second, you shouldn't post homework.

Answer (score 3):

$\begin{matrix} C^{-1}AX+Y=C^{-1}BAC\\  B^{-1}CX-Y=B^{-1}CAB \end{matrix}$

Great, add the two together.

$(C^{-1}A+B^{-1}C)X=C^{-1}BAC + B^{-1}CAB\\
X=(C^{-1}A+B^{-1}C)^{-1}C^{-1}BAC + B^{-1}CAB $

It may feel a little labor intensive to calculate that all out, but it isn't really that big of a killer.

$Y = C^{-1}BAC - C^{-1}AX$

Comment: Nice solution! Just to add, since $C$ is invertible, you can simplify $(C^{-1}A + B^{-1}C)^{-1} C^{-1} BAC$ further into $(A + C B^{-1} C)^{-1} BAC$. Not much simpler, but one matrix less. ;-)

Comment: Why not? $(C^{-1}A + B^{-1}C)^{-1} = (C^{-1}[A + CB^{-1}C])^{-1} = [A + CB^{-1}C]^{-1} C$, using $(XY)^{-1} = Y^{-1} X^{-1}$ in the second step.

Comment: @florian Thanks, I see what you are saying now.